# What's the difference between MSI's N660 Gaming and N660 TF GPU editions?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

Hardware manufacturer MSI has a couple of versions of Nvidia's GTX 660 GPU. I'm building a new mid-range gaming rig and so I would like to know the difference between following graphics cards:

- [The Gaming edition](http://be.msi.com/product/vga/N660-Gaming-2GD5-OC.html#overview)
- [The Twin Frozr edition](http://be.msi.com/product/vga/N660-TF-2GD5-OC.html)

Both are the factory overclocked versions to the same core speed, and both have 2GB of GDDR5 memory. The other specs are all the same and the gaming editions also has Twin Frozr fans.

I really wonder why do they make these two products? Is it just marketing? The gaming edition is slightly cheaper where I buy btw.

Comment: They are the exact same product except for the color of the PCB.

Comment: @Ramhound I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comparison view on newegg.com = 
[image: msi items]

The Gaming version comes with a bunch of apps as well it seems:

Gaming App or features that are not noted in the non gaming version:

> OC Mode - Tune up core clock and fan speed to gain a best performance.
>   Gaming Mode - Provide a stable gaming experience with higher core
>   clock. Silent Mode - The best operating environment with extremely low
>   noise.
>
> Experience - Predator
>   -Just use Predator within Afterburner for "FREE"!
>   -Audio source selection support.
>   -Screen capturing support.
>   -BMP/JPG/PNG format support.